# Detect whether cyclic reference in object A is structurally the same as cyclic reference in object B

Tags: javascript, object, cyclic-reference

I am implementing a function that compares two JavaScript objects for "deep" equality.  The skeleton of this function, right now, looks like this:

```
function check_equal(actual, expected) {
    var stack = [];
    function check_equal_r(act, exp) {
        if (is_scalar(act) || is_scalar(exp)) {
            assert(act === exp);

        } else if (stack.indexOf(act) == -1) {
            assert(have_all_the_same_properties(act, exp));
            stack.push(act);
            for (var k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exp)) {
                check_equal_r(act[k], exp[k]);
            }
            stack.pop(act);

        } else {
            // ??? cyclic reference detected
        }
    }
    check_equal_r(act, exp);
}
```

The question is what to put where it says `// ??? cyclic reference detected`.  Ideally, I would like to be able to say that these objects are deep-equal:

```
var a = {foo:1, bar:2, baz:null},
    b = {foo:1, bar:2, baz:null};
a.baz = a;
b.baz = b;
```

and these objects are *not* deep-equal:

```
var a = { car: 1, cdr: { car: 2, cdr: null } };
var b = { car: 1, cdr: { car: 2, cdr: null } };
a.cdr.cdr = a;
b.cdr.cdr = b.cdr;
```

Notes:

- `assert` throws an exception if its argument is false.
- `have_all_the_same_properties(x, y)` throws an exception if the `getOwnPropertyNames` lists of `x` and `y` are not identical.
- `is_scalar(x)` is *effectively* the same as `typeof x !== 'object'`.
- I used a for-of loop in the code above for brevity's sake, but ES6 features are **not** available in the interpreter this will actually run on.

Comment: Do you mean `is_scalar(x)` is the same as `typeof x !== 'object'`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a lot of time to give it a shot, but the way I would approach is, during your recursive operation, keep a stack for `exp` as well. When you unexpectedly find an `indexOf` match as you're doing, *compare that numerical index*. (If the objects are the same so far, a matching index means the same structure)

Comment: @ChrisHunt Er, yes, I meant `!==` there.  It's not *exactly* the same but the difference does not matter for purpose of this question -- e.g. in the full version of this code, `Date` objects get compared by `getTime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty easy extension to your algorithm that checks for circular references. It keeps the `exp` corresponding to each `act` object on a separate stack, such that it will have the same index as any `act` which is referenced within itself.

```
function is_scalar(v) {
    return typeof v !== 'object';
}

function have_all_the_same_properties(x, y) {
    var xprops = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x),
        yprops = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(y);
    if (xprops.length === yprops.length) {
        return xprops.every(function (prop) {
            return yprops.indexOf(prop) !== -1;
        });
    }
    return false;
}

function check_equal(actual, expected) {
    var stack = [];
    var expected_stack = [];
    function check_equal_r(act, exp) {
        if (is_scalar(act) || is_scalar(exp)) {
            return act === exp;
        } else {
            var i = stack.indexOf(act);
            if (i == -1) {
                if (have_all_the_same_properties(act, exp)) {
                    stack.push(act);
                    expected_stack.push(exp);
                    var res = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exp).every(function (k) {
                        return check_equal_r(act[k], exp[k]);
                    });
                    expected_stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    return res;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return expected_stack[i] === exp;
            }
        }
    }
    return check_equal_r(actual, expected);
}

var a = {foo:1, bar:2, baz:null},
    b = {foo:1, bar:2, baz:null};
a.baz = a;
b.baz = b;

console.log(check_equal(a, b));

var c = { car: 1, cdr: { car: 2, cdr: null } };
var d = { car: 1, cdr: { car: 2, cdr: null } };
c.cdr.cdr = c;
d.cdr.cdr = d.cdr;

console.log(check_equal(c, d));
```

Comment: I'd call it `expected_stack` not `map` :-)

Comment: This looks promising.  I will need to do a bit more testing on it before I am confident it works in wackier cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Chris is correct. I recently wrote a util function for deep equality check and need to cover circular dependencies too. Here is the code on github (https://github.com/ryancat/simple-deep-equal) which also covers NaN case as well.